# how to build a php search engine with custom fields

Tags: php, search, github

I need to build a search engine in php that will help in retrieving the products/items from the backend using the search criteria with specified fields.

Can anyone provide me with any help tutorial or any plugin for wordpress or joomla.

```
http://www/github.com
```

i have searched on github but still no success

Comment: is it a search engine or search feature for the website ? wordpress or joomla owns there self made custom search features, you can customize that according to your requirement

Comment: like custom search functionality by which i can easily search out the desired products from backend

Comment: like in magento based websites we can easily search out the desired products... something similar to that

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unlike most similar sites on the web, this isn't a discussion board. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) regarding what kind of questions do and don't belong here. The new [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) is also a great read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) and at [PHP Sphinx clien](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sphinx.php).